# Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node

Tags: node.js

Building node project results in

```
Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node
```

I have no idea why this is happening. It succeded to build the other day.

package.json and package-lock.json are on my github https://github.com/HoosierTransfer/unblocker

The build logs are

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 18.x...
       Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried to roll back the package.json and package-lock.json but that didnt fix anything.

Comment: Based on the error, I had a quick look on the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version and they suggest to add the `engines` section with your npm/node version. In your package json I don't see them.

Comment: @JStw this didn't change the error, with engines specification or none I get the same error: with specification: `Error: Unknown error installing "^16.13.1" of node` without: `Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku recently changed their default Node version from `16` to `18`:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2487

If you used a different version in your project (for example `16`), it could now break during build. Adding it to your `package.json` file should fix this:

```json
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
}
```

If your not sure which version you need, go to your project in your terminal, run `node --version`, and use the (major) version that's displayed there.

Comment: this didn't change the error, with engines specification or none I get the same error: 
with specification: `Error: Unknown error installing "^16.13.1" of node`
without:`Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node`